# applications --> keycloak --> azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak, openvpn

I'm currently trying to implement openvpn server authenticated with keycloak.
This part is actually working well with user added in keycloak but now I want to authenticate my openvpn user with azure AD.
I made the configuration to be able to authenticate user with keycloak and azure AD has identity provider so this part  work well but not I want to conbine both
I would like that my user will be authtenticated with azure AD throw keycloak when they execute OpenVPN client.
I have 1 realm. The account clients work properly with Azure AD and I have a Clients for OpenVPN but How to link both

Comment: Hi @JonathanCOLLIN, if the provided answer resolved your issue, you may mark it as answer or upvote it so that others who encounter the similar issue, it may be useful for them or community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   As per the described query, you want to authenticate with Azure AD through Keycloak while connecting with OpenVPN client. Thus, accordingly, you will have to **configure the VPN client for P2S OpenVPN protocol connection in Azure AD** first. For that purpose, kindly follow the below documentation link which describes the steps to be followed for registering and configuring **‘Azure VPN’ as an application in Azure AD** and further configuring the VPN configuration settings on it as well: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-wan/virtual-wan-point-to-site-azure-ad**

•   Once, the above-mentioned steps are done as stated, then you will have to `register an application as a client service principal in your Azure AD, create a client secret for it and register the same in keycloak administration console` as mentioned in the below link. This will ensure that your keycloak integration with Azure AD is complete and working fine as well as the **authentication for your Azure AD users through keycloak is possible over OpenVPN client such as Azure VPN client**.

**https://blog.hcltechsw.com/versionvault/how-to-configure-microsoft-azure-active-directory-as-keycloak-identity-provider-to-enable-single-sign-on-for-hcl-compass/**

The above document states for **‘HCL Compass’** as the target application to be connected via **keycloak via Azure AD identity** but you can **configure the same as per your own SaaS application to be integrated**.

Comment: Hi!!
Thanks for your reply, I have still followed this blog to allow keycloak to connect to Azure AD the problem is when I try to connect with openvpn I have to use a password stored in Keycloak and it's not the same that I have in Azure AD, I'm not able to find a way to say to keycloak to check the password from Azure AD

Comment: Is keycloak integrated correctly with Azure AD?? Can you login to keycloak with Azure AD credentials, if yes then you should be able to do so. Also, try to use the client system as Azure AD joined which will help you to connect to Azure AD through keycloak much better.

Comment: Hi, It's was my thought but I have to review the configuration of the client for OPENVPN has I use credentials to allow the communication between the openvpn server and keycloak, and my client to allow the authentication with azure ad don't have it